# Spring Hibernate and PostgresSQL Full Text Search

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, full-text-search

How to implement FTS with Hibernate, Spring and PostgresSQL. Can I put some paramters in Hibernate `@Formula` annotation so I could put `score` as extra select paramter:

```
select *,
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(title || ' ' || code || ' ' || line1 || ' ' || postal || ' ' || city),
                  to_tsquery('LA | Los Anageles')) AS score
from customer
where score > 0
order by score desc;
```

and how to do it with Spirng Specifications, now I have:

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(search)) {
    spec = Objects.requireNonNull(spec).and((root, query, cb) -> cb.or(
            cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Customer_.title)), "%" + search.toLowerCase() + "%"),
            cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Customer_.code)), "%" + search.toLowerCase() + "%"),
            cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Customer_.address).get(Address_.line1)), search.toLowerCase() + "%"),
            cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Customer_.address).get(Address_.postal)), search.toLowerCase() + "%"),
            cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Customer_.address).get(Address_.city)), search.toLowerCase() + "%")
    ));
}
```

could I used at least cb.function withoud sorting by score?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement a custom `SQLFunction` and register that under a name in Hibernate. You can then use the function by that name through `cb.function`.

Alternatively you should also be able to use the following:

```
cb.function("ts_rank_cd", String.class,
  cb.function("to_tsvector", String.class, 
    cb.concat(...), 
    cb.function("to_tsquery", String.class, cb.literal("LA | Los Anageles"))
  )
).as(Double.class);
```

This should result in SQL similar to this:

```
cast(ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(title || ' ' || code || ' ' || line1 || ' ' || postal || ' ' || city), to_tsquery('LA | Los Anageles')) as double precision)
```